# Ошибка во время миграции

Tags: c#, entity-framework, миграция

Проект приложение windows service/служба, после какого то момента перестала работать миграция и получаю вот такую ошибку, не могу понять чего он трогает EFCore, к проекту подключен EF6, core вообще работает по-моему только в asp.net core. Указанный пакет добавлять пробовал, ошибка такая же. В чем может быть проблема?

> Your startup project '' doesn't reference
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design. This package is required for the
>   Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your startup project is
>   correct, install the package, and try again.

Comment: Как Startup Project в solution у вас выбран именно тот проект, в котором есть референс?

Comment: @PashaPash да..

Comment: @PashaPash проект не на asp.net core он же не должен просить этот пакет да?